# Linearregression of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, linear-regression

I have two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': -4, 'B': -3, 'C': -2, 'D': -1, 'E': 2, 'F': 4, 'G': 8, 'H': 6, 'I': -2}])
```

df2 looks like this (just a cutout; in total there are ~100 rows).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [220412004, 220412004, 220412004, 220412006], 'A': [-0.15584, -0.11446, -0.1349, -0.0458], 'B': [-0.11826, -0.0833, -0.1025, -0.0216], 'C': [-0.0611, -0.0413, -0.0645, -0.0049], 'D': [-0.04461, -0.022693, -0.0410, 0.0051], 'E': [0.0927, 0.0705, 0.0923, 0.0512], 'F': [0.1453, 11117, 0.1325, 0.06205], 'G': [0.30077, 0.2274, 0.2688, 0.1077], 'H': [0.2449, 0.1860, 0.2274, 0.09328], 'I': [-0.0706, -0.0612, -0.0704, -0.02953]})

    Date          A           B            C          D          E         F         G           H       I
3   220412004   -0.15584    -0.11826    -0.0611    -0.04461    0.0927   0.1453    0.30077    0.2449   -0.0706
4   220412004   -0.11446    -0.0833     -0.0413    -0.022693   0.0705   0.11117   0.2274     0.1860   -0.0612
5   220412004   -0.1349     -0.1025     -0.0645    -0.0410     0.0923   0.1325    0.2688     0.2274   -0.0704
7   220412006   -0.0458     -0.0216     -0.0049     0.0051     0.0512   0.06205   0.1077     0.09328  -0.02953
```

Now I want to iterate through df2 and make a linear regression of each row (of df2) as y-axis with df as base (x-Axis).

My approach was:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
     reg = np.polyfit(df, row, 1)
     predict = np.poly1d(reg) 
     trend = np.polyval(reg, df)
     std = row.std() 
     r2 = np.round(r2_score(row.values, predict(df)), 5)
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Any ideas? Thx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by make a linear regression of each row? Make a linear regression model?

Comment: First I want to make a linear regression of df2.iloc[1] (=y-axis) and df (=x-axis; df just exist of one row). Then I want to make a linear regression of df2.iloc[2] (=y-axis) and df (=x-axis). And so on.

Comment: I need to calculate the slope and R^2 for each row of df2 with df as x-axis

Comment: So you want to make an LR model on each column?

Comment: No, I want to make a LR model on each row. I made an example with excel here:  https://imgur.com/a/5zKOekC

Comment: Your code seems weird to me. First of all, pay attention that in `df2` you have the `Date` column which I think can cause a mistake for LR. The second point, what is `x()`? Where do you define it? And the last point, can you specify which line of your code has an error?

Comment: @MohammadrezaRiahi hmm maybe move the `Date` column to the index? Oh you're right with `x()`, that was a copy - paste error. It must have been (I think): `std = row.std()`. The error occurs on this line:  `reg = np.polyfit(df, row, 1)`. Edit: I set the `Date` as Index then I get the error `TypeError: expected 1D vector for x` for the same line. The same happens if I transpose `df2`, `df` or both.

Comment: Moving the `Date` column to the index is okay. I will run your codes and come back to you with updates.

Comment: @MohammadrezaRiahi were you able to reproduce and maybe solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the Numpy indicates that the `x` and `y` in `polyfit` function have `shape (M,)` and `shape (M,) or (M, K)`. You do not comply with this agreement for the `x` and 'y'. It should be used like `np.polyfit(df.values[0], row.values, 1)`.

**Note that the date must be passed to the index.**

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, now I get `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc lstsq_n`. Any ideas?

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: reg = np.polyfit(df.values[0], row.values, 1)

Comment: I do not face this error. My Numpy version is 1.22.3

Comment: I found the problem: My dtype was somehow an object. I converted it into float. Now it works, except: `r2 = np.round(r2_score(row.values, predict(df2)), 5)` This throws the error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [9, 1]` Any idea? And how can I store `reg`, `predict`, `trend`, `std` and `r2` for each index of df2 into df2?

Comment: `r2_score` requires `y_true` and `y_pred`. In your code, the `row.values.shape==(9,)` and `predict(df2).shape==(9, 4)`. This error is because of mismatch dimensions.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I found the error: df2 has to be transposed: r2 = np.round(r2_score(row.values, predict(df2.T)), 5). How can I save these results into new columns of df2?

Comment: Are you sure? I got error when running `r2 = np.round(r2_score(row.values, predict(df2.T)), 5)`. The error is `ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=4)`.

Comment: For adding new items in a new column of a data frame, you can use the following structure: `df2['r2']=[1, 2, 3, 4]` where the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` should have the same rows with df2.

Comment: Thx! But somehow strange, on my computer the code runs.

Comment: I think your code is `r2 = np.round(r2_score(row.values, predict(df.T)), 5)` not `df2.T`.

Comment: Damn, you're right! :-) I should take a break from the computer for an hour or so... I'm totally code-blind right now.